# Property get always null value in mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working with c# and ASP.NET MVC4. I have a model class

```
 public class Category {
    private Category _parent;
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; private set; }
    public Category Parent {
        get {

            if (this._parent == null) {
                _parent = new Category(this.ParentId);
            }

            return _parent;
        }
        set {
            _parent = value;
        }
    }
 }
```

In the View I have a text input and a dropdown list for selecting the name and parent category:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="product name" class="form-control" name="name">
@Html.DropDownList("category", new SelectList(ViewBag.Category, "Id", "Name"), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

When I submit the form to the following Controller Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddCategory(string category_NA, Category category_Parent) 
{
       ................
}
```

I always get the category_Parent as null.

Can anyone help with this please? Thanks.

Comment: A `<select>` posts back a single value (or an array for multiple selects), not a complex object.

Comment: @StephenMuecke: then how can i solve this problem

Comment: It looks like `ParentID` is the ID of the parent category. Is that correct?

Comment: Then you need to bind to `ParentId` and change the method parameter to `int ParentID`. Your code generated a select with `name="category"` which would not have bound anyway since neither of you method parameters has the name `category`. Then call the database to populate the `Parent` property if needed.

Comment: As a side note, use the strongly typed helpers `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name) and @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ParentID, new ...)` so you inputs are always correctly named to match you model properties (and you have a parameter named `category_NA` but don't seem to have an input with the same name so that will be null also)